# Wrap an entire DBUnit/JUnit Test under a single transaction

Tags: java, junit, dbunit

I have searched around but have been unsuccessful in determining whether the following approach is possible / good practice. Basically what I would like to do is the following:

Create JUnit Tests which use DBUnit to initialize the data. Run multiple test methods each which run off of the same initial dataset. Rollback after each test method back to the state right after the initial setUp function. After all test methods have run rollback any changes that were made in the setUp function. At this point the data in the database should be exactly the same as it was prior to running the JUnit test class.

Ideally I would not have to reinitialize the data before each test case because I could just roll back to the state right after setUp.

I have been able to roll back individual test methods but have been unable to roll back changes made in setUp after all test methods have run.

NOTE: I am aware of the different functionality of DBUnit such as CLEAN_INSERT, DELETE etc. I am using the Spring framework to inject my dataSource.

An example layout would look like:

```
public class TestClass {

    public void setUp() {
        // Calls a method in a different class which uses DBUnit to initialize the database
    }

    public void runTest1() {
        // Runs a test which may insert / delete data in the database
        // After running the test the database is in the same state as it was
        // after running setUp
    }

    public void runTest2() {
        // Runs a test which may insert / delete data in the database
        // After running the test the database is in the same state as it was
        // after running setUp
    }

    // After runTest1 and runTest2 have finished the database will be rolled back to the
    // state before any of the methods above had run.
    // The data will be unchanged as if this class had never even been run
}
```

I would be running the tests in a development database however I would prefer to not affect any data currently in the database. I am fine with running CLEAN_INSERT at the start to initialize the data however after all test methods have run I would like the data back to how it was before I ran my JUnit test.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as "setUp" JUnit offers a "tearDown" method executed after each test method. that you could use to rollback. Also starting with JUnit 4 you have the following annotations:

- @BeforeClass: run once before running any of your tests in the test case
- @Before: run every time before a test method
- @After: run every time after a test method
- @AfterClass: run once after all your tests in the current suite have been executed

Answer (score 1):

We solved a similar problem at the [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) open source project. Please take a look at the code residing at engine\backend\manager\modules\dal\src\test\java\org\ovirt\engine\core\dao\BaseDAOTestCase.java. 
In general look at what we did there at the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methods. You can use it on per method basis. We used the Spring-test framework for that.